# Retrieving and deserializing large lists of Redis-cache items

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, system.text.json

We're planning to add a Redis-cache to an existing solution.

We have this core entity which is fetched a lot, several times per session. The entity consists of 13 columns where the majority is less than 20 characters. Typically it's retrieved by parent id, but sometimes as a subset that is fetched by a list of ids. To solve this we're thinking of implementing the solution below, but the question is if it's a good idea? Typically the list is around 400 items, but in some cases it could be up to 3000 items.

We would store the instances in the list with this key pattern: `EntityName:{ParentId}:{ChildId}`, where `ParentId` and `ChildId` is ints.

Then to retrieve the list based on `ParentId` we would call the below method with `EntityName:{ParentId}:*` as the value of the pattern-argument:

```cs
public async Task<List<T>> GetMatches<T>(string pattern)
{
    var keys = _multiPlexer.GetServer(_multiPlexer.GetEndPoints(true)[0]).Keys(pattern: pattern).ToArray();
    var values = await Db.StringGetAsync(keys: keys);

    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var value in values.Where(x => x.HasValue))
    {
        result.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value));
    }

    return result;
}
```

And to retrieve a specific list of items we would call the below method with a list of exact keys:

```cs
public async Task<List<T>> GetList<T>(string[] keys)
{
    var values = await Db.StringGetAsync(keys: keys.Select(x => (RedisKey)x).ToArray());

    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var value in values.Where(x => x.HasValue))
    {
        result.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value));
    }

    return result;
}
```

The obvious worry here is the amount of objects to deserialize and the performance of `System.Text.Json`.

A alternative to this would be to store the data twice, both as a list and on it's own, but that would only help in the case where we're fetching by `ParentId`. We could also only store the data as a list and retrieve it every time only to sometimes use a subset.

Is there a better way to tackle this?

All input is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

**Edit**

I wrote a small console application to load test the alternatives, fetching 2000 items 100 times took 2020ms with the pattern matching and fetching the list took 1568ms. I think we can live with that difference and go with the pattern matching.

Comment: Since Redis is just a simple key-value store and not a search database the best you can do is duplicate the data with different keys that are optimized for how you want to look it up. Alternatively you should look into whether your application can be structured differently; if you can avoid looking up lists I think that is preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sure I realise that that is the preferred way and maybe we could refactor so that that would be possible. But if we where to go with this solution, is the problematic part the deserialization or redis mget?

Comment: Unfortunately you'd have to do some performance profiling to figure that out. It's largely dependent on your setup and settings you use for both the Redis server and JSON serializer as well as the size of the objects. But what's the alternative to JSON deserializing? You always need some way of deserializing data transferred between processes.

Comment: Sure, I was considering protobuf as an alternative to json, but yeah, it doesn't really change the fact. I'll do some profiling to see where the additional 500ms lies and do some stress testing to see the effects on the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like @Xerillio was right. I did some load testing using hosted services and then it was almost three times slower to fetch the list using the pattern matching, slower then receiving the list directly from SQL. So, to answer my own question if it's a good idea, I would say no it isn't. The majority of the added time was not because of deserialization rather because of fetching the keys using the pattern matching.

Here's the result from fetching 2000 items 100 items in a loop:

- Fetch directly from db = 8625ms
- Fetch using list of exact keys = 5663ms
- Fetch using match = 13098ms
- Fetch full list = 5352ms

Comment: You could potentially try mget or hget instead of 100 items in a loop... Just build the key array and mget.  Based on your timings - mget would in 1500ms range.